# RequireJS seems to be ignoring my path definitions ( I'm not calling require() in the html). Why?

Tags: javascript, html, requirejs

I've been researching this question a lot.  I know a common issue is caused with asynchronous loading before require has been defined.  I dont think that's the issue that I'm experiencing.  I'm declaring **baseURL** and **paths** in a config file, but I always get an error that the scripts can't be found because it seems to ignore my paths and just look from the baseURL.

This is my folder structure

```
index.html
js/
  app/
     jsonLoader.js
     notionalAddGraph.js
  lib/
  config.js
  require.js
```

There's nothing in lib, but I'm mimicking the structure of a project that I'm working on.  Here is the html for the page.

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Blah Blah Blah</title>
    <script data-main="js/config.js" src="js/require.js"></script>
    <script id="graphData" type="application/json">
    {
      "json": "Is better than",
      "global": "but it requires a change to the authoring",
      "environment": "also, because of the JSON.parse",
      "required": "it is probably slower too"
    }
    </script>

</head>
```

Here is the code for config.js

config.js:

```
require({
    baseUrl: 'js/lib',
    paths: {
      app: '../app'
    },
    urlArgs: 'bust=' + (new Date()).getTime()
});

require(['app/jsonLoader','app/notionalAddGraph'],
    function(require) {
      'use strict';
});
```

and here is the code for jsonLoader.js

jsonLoader.js:

```
define(function() {
  var jsonString = document.getElementById('graphData').textContent;
  return JSON.parse(jsonString);
})
```

annnd here is the code for notionalAddGraph.js

notionalAddGraph.js:

```
define([
  'jsonLoader'
], function(json) {

  console.log(json.required);
});
```

so every time that I try this, require tries to load **js/lib/jsonloader.js** and fails because it should be looking under app, not lib. Oddly enough, if I intentionally specify the incorrect path when I define **app**, requireJS will at least look for jsonLoader where I told it to.  Obviously though, its not there, because I specified the wrong path.  When I specify the correct path, it doesn't work and tries to load from baseURL. I've tried changing everything I can imagine for config.js, but nothing seems to work.  I've copied the format directly from requireJS API, but still nothing.  Does anyone have an idea as to what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In notionalAddGraph.js you have define with `'jsonLoader'` so its looking in the correct path as expected, add `../` to your define and should work correctly

Comment: Sigh. Two hours down the drain for another simple mistake. Thanks for saving me another two.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what i'd try

First, call the scripts using an absolute path (you can rollback this change later, but it's just to be on the safe side)

```
<script data-main="/js/config.js" src="/js/require.js"></script>
```

Second, declare the config parameters using `requirejs.config`. I guess that the way you're doing now they are just variables.

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'js/lib',
    paths: {
      app: '../app'
    },
    urlArgs: 'bust=' + (new Date()).getTime()
});
```

Third, the return of the jsonLoader isn't the require object, but the object that comes from parsing the jsonString. The way you're doing now is replacing the require object.

```
require(['app/jsonLoader','app/notionalAddGraph'],  function(jsonObject) {
      'use strict';
    console.log('require is still', require, 'and jsonobject is ',jsonObject);
});
```